# Графический интерфейс vnc на ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как установить графический интерфейс vnc на ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

в термниале введите команду :

```
$ aptitude search vnc
```

найдете там строки следущего содержания:

p   gvncviewer                                                               - VNC-монитор, использующий gtk-vnc                                               
p   libgtk-vnc-1.0-0                                                         - A VNC viewer widget for GTK+ (runtime libraries)                                
p   libgtk-vnc-1.0-0-dbg                                                     - A VNC viewer widget for GTK+ (runtime libraries)                                
p   libgtk-vnc-1.0-dev                                                       - A VNC viewer widget for GTK+ (development files)

последущая операция,устанвока необходимого пакета:

```
$ sudo aptitude install gtk-vnc
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, правильно ли я тебя понял, но попробуй программу x11vnc

Answer (score 0):

[Удаленный доступ в Ubuntu Linux (VNC)](http://startubuntu.ru/?p=129)

> Здесь все очень просто: сервер и клиент VNC включены в стандартную комплектацию Ubuntu Desktop. На компьютере с Ubuntu, которым мы собираемся управлять, идем в меню «Система — Параметры — Удаленный рабочий стол», и выставляем нужные настройки.

В дополнение: [VNC Software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC#VNC_Software).

Comment: Я его понял так, что ему нужно управление сервером. Ну а если просто клиентская программа, то tsclient подойдёт, да.